# Unable to receive proper predicted data from Dynamics 365 Customer Insights platform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, dynamics-365, azure-machine-learning-service

I am new to the microsoft customer insights API. we are trying to train a model with customer dataset and created the entity by prediction. we are trying to consume the churn prediction scores using the API from below

https://home.ci.ai.dynamics.com/

We have tried almost all the api requests present there to get the churnscore for a user. we are not getting anything. is there any way to fetch those.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the [Transactional churn prediction (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-insights/audience-insights/predict-transactional-churn) and see if it suits your scenario or not. In case if you see [failure then try to troubleshoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-insights/audience-insights/predict-transactional-churn#troubleshoot-a-failed-prediction) and see how it helps.